# Sequence of Nonnegative Measurable Functions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

While working through problems, I came upon one that I couldn't figure out and was wondering how to do. Here's the problem:

Find a sequence $\{f_n\}^\infty_{n=1}$ of nonnegative measurable functions such that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} \int f_n = 0,$ but $\displaystyle\limsup_{n\to\infty} f_n(x) = + \infty$ for all $x.$

Is this a classical example? I've never seen it before if so...

Edit: the domain of integration is $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: for all $x\in \mathbb{R}.$ I think the idea is to take something like the sequence $f_0, f_1, \ldots$, where $f_{n(n-1)/2 + j}$ is the characteristic function on $[j/n, (j+1)/n].$ Obviously some modification must be made for this to work though... and I'm not seeing how to extend it to all of the reals

Comment: edited my answer. Hope the new one helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found a different simpler idea. The easiest way is to use two indices.
Assume first $x\geq 0$.

Basically, the idea is to split the interval $[0,2^k]$ into $2^{4k}$ pieces of height $2^k$ and width $2^{-2k}$.

Define the function $$f_{k,l}(x):=2^k\chi_{[l2^{-2k},(l+1)2^{-2k}]}(x)$$
and think of $0\leq l \leq 2^{4k}-1$. Obviously for $k,l$ fixed the Integral is $2^k 2^{-2k}=2^{-k}$ hence $\int f_{k,l}\to 0$ for $k\to\infty$.

For fixed $k$ we see that 
$$[0,2^k]=\bigcup_{l=1}^{2^{4k}-1} [l2^{-2k},(l+1)2^{-2k}].$$
Thus for every point in $x\in[0,2^k]$ there exist an $l\in (0,2^{4k}-1)$ and hence there is an $l$ such that $f_{k,l}(x)=2^k$.

Now all we have to do is define $g_n$ appropriately in terms of $k,l$. For example. After increasing $k$ by one we have to go through all the $l$ values from $0$ to $2^{4k}-1$. Then increase $k$ again and so forth.

Finally you can choose the sequence $h_n(x)=g_n(x)+g_n(-x)$ to cover all points of $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: I want $\limsup f_n(x) = +\infty$ everywhere though.

Comment: To me it seems that $\limsup_{n\to\infty} f_{n}(x)=0$ for all $x\neq 0$ in this example.

Comment: thanks, updated my idea :)

Comment: Why does this $g_{n}$ do the job? You only get $+\infty$ with $f_{n}$ in the origin, and everywhere else $0$. How do you enumerate $\mathbb{Q}$ so that for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\varepsilon>0$ you find $k\in\mathbb{N}$ with $|q_{n}+x|<\varepsilon$ for all $n\geq k$. You can't have $0$ appearing infinitely often in the sequence $(q_{n}+x)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$, so I don't really see why this example works. Could you elaborate more on it?

Comment: i was actually just about to say that; you don't know that every real appears infinitely many times.

Comment: @ thomas: you are right. One does not know if one finds for given $x\in R$ infinitely many points that are $1/n^2$ close to $x$.

Comment: And in the end, for $\limsup_{n\to\infty} f_{n}(q_{n}+x)$ to equal $+\infty$‚ you would need the sequence $(q_{n}+x)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ to contain $0$ infinitely often, which is not possible as it only contains it once (or never if $x$ is irrational). This requirement is because the limsup of $f_{n}$ is $+\infty$ only in the origin.

Comment: yeah you're right. I think I have another idea but still need to work on it. I will post it later. It has to do with some "traveling" to overcome the problem with limsup being infinte only in $0$.

Comment: About the edited answer: What indices do you consider to the sum in $g_{n}$? Note that $f_{k,n}(x)$ was defined only for $k\leq x$, which may be none if e.g. $0<x<1$. If you sum over all $k$‚ then to me it seems that $\int g_{n}= +\infty$ for any $n$, as the intervals $[k,k+2^{2n+k}]$ cover $[0,\infty)$ and $g_{n}$ is increasing.

Comment: you're of course right, it should be $2^{-2k+2}$. However I found a much simpler example. I'm going to formulate it properly and post it in a couple of minutes

Comment: yes, in fact there's something even easier i think

Comment: if you simply consider a function like $n$ and partition the interval $(-n, n)$ into say $n^3$ pieces.

Comment: thats what i did above :) I considered the interval $[0,2^k]$ height was $2^k$ and I had $2^{4k}$ pieces. But the idea is the same. And finding the idea is much easier than writing it down properly :)

Comment: yes that's basically the same - just without exponents would probably be easier to read =P. I've accepted your answer btw

Comment: I just edited it with a shorter explanation which essentially contains your previous comment :)